# Typescript object iteration compiler problems

Tags: typescript

Given the following code in a file named `test.ts`:

```
interface ImageFile {
    width: number;
    height: number;
    url: string;
}

interface ImageFiles {
    low: ImageFile;
    medium?: ImageFile;
    high?: ImageFile;
}

let images: ImageFiles = {
    low: {
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        url: 'bla'
    }
};

Object.keys(images).forEach((k) => {
    let img = images[k];
    // do something with img
});
```

Gives the following error when compiling with --noImplicitAny option:

```
$ tsc test.ts --noImplicitAny
test.ts(22,10): error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Meaning that `images[k]` type implicitly has an `any`type, and also, type casting won't work here.

Compiling without `--noImplicitAny` flag works ok.

How can I correctly iterate through an object when the above flag is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler cannot infer the correct type for `images[k]`, and that's why it is complaining. As you've discovered, type casting does not fix the problem.

Instead, you can use an [index signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.9.4) to tell the compiler that all properties of an `ImageFiles` object are of type `ImageFile`:

```
interface ImageFiles {
    [key: string]: ImageFile;
    low: ImageFile;
    medium?: ImageFile;
    high?: ImageFile;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Thanks!